# Doctrine : join not workin as expected

Tags: php, doctrine

*Note: I use Doctrine as a standalone project, not with Symfony framework.*

I have two entities with a OneToMany/ManoToOne mapping.

The first one is a product family:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
class Family {
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER), ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 50)]
    private string $name;

    /**
     * @var Collection<Subfamily>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'family', targetEntity: Subfamily::class)]
    private Collection $subfamilies;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->subfamilies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then there is product subfamily:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
class Subfamily {
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER), ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 50)]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Family::class, inversedBy: 'subfamilies'), ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private Family $family;

    // ...
}
```

Now I want to get the list of families (and if possible only the matching subfamilies in `Family->subfamiles` property) where the *subfamily* name ends with "-1".
I tried to wrote the following query:

```php
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(<<<'DQL'
SELECT f, s
FROM Tests\Entities\Entities\Family f
JOIN Tests\Entities\Entities\Subfamily s
WHERE s.name LIKE '%-1'
DQL
);

$families = $query->getResult();
foreach ($families as $family) {
    echo get_class($family) . ' : ' . ($family instanceof Family ? $family->getName() : '') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

But I don't get the expected results. It return me **all** the families (even if they have no subfamilies at all) and matching subfamilies in separate entities:

```
Tests\Entities\Entities\Family : Famille 1
Tests\Entities\Entities\Subfamily : 
Tests\Entities\Entities\Family : Famille 2
Tests\Entities\Entities\Family : Famille 3
Tests\Entities\Entities\Subfamily : 
Tests\Entities\Entities\Subfamily :
```

If I check the Mysql query used by Doctrine, the JOIN has no ON condition :

```mysql
SELECT f0_.id AS id_0, f0_.name AS name_1, s1_.id AS id_2, s1_.name AS name_3, s1_.family_id AS family_id_4
FROM Family f0_ 
  INNER JOIN Subfamily s1_ 
WHERE s1_.name LIKE '%-1'
```

But according to documentation and all examples found arround, I don't need to explicit the WITH in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in join:

change: **JOIN Tests\Entities\Entities\Subfamily s**
to: **JOIN f.subfamilies s**

result:

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(<<<'DQL'
SELECT f, s
FROM Tests\Entities\Entities\Family f
JOIN f.subfamilies s
WHERE s.name LIKE '%-1'
DQL
);
```